# Clover maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, clover

After I replace version 4.1.2 clover-maven-plugin instead of version 3.1.3 maven-clover2-plugin, and then i got an error as below:[image]

But i am confused with "Renewals and upgrades of Clover are no longer available effective April 11, 2017. If you require an upgrade to a different license tier we recommend switching to the open-source version. Open-source Clover does not require a license tier and offers unlimited usage."
https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/clover#-4

Can someone help have look?

Comment: Should i upgrade license? or there have other a way configuration for free for using clover maven plugin

Comment: Migrate to the open source version; it looks like Atlassian are no longer going to charge you to use it.

Comment: @SteveC finally, I used org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin instead of com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin
it is just artifact id and group id difference, and not change other configuration, but also free

Answer (score 3):

Atlassian has open-sourced Clover on April 11, 2017. It means that all binaries published before this date are the commercial ones and thus they require a license key. It applies to all Clover versions up to 4.1.2. Please note that historically the Maven Clover Plugin has been renamed, so its artifactId is:

- maven-clover2-plugin till version 4.0.6
- clover-maven-plugin for versions 4.1.1-4.1.2

In order to use the open-source version of Clover, you have to build it from sources (Atlassian published source code only and does not host any open-source binaries at the moment).

However, as Clover-lover :-) I've prepared binaries - they're named OpenClover. It's a fork based on Atlassian Clover sources. See the website: http://openclover.org. The Maven plugin is `org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin`, as Haven Lin wrote.